# $request->validated() returns not only validated items, but everything

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am using `FormRequest` to validate data, which looks like this:

```
public function authorize(): bool
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255']
    ];
}
```

But if I send request like:

```
{
    "first_name": "Random",
    "last_name": "Guy"
}
```

Then $request->validated(), just like bellow example, is returning both, first and last names.

```
public function create(UserRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->validated();
    return $data;
}
```

Any idea why is this happening? As far as I know, `validated()` must only return keys that exist in rules

Comment: `validated()` was never meant to return only input that has a rule. You can achieve that with `->only(['first_name'])`

Comment: @N69S it does indeed only return the fields that were in the rules array & are validated. @randomacc have you tried cleaning the cache? Also, is the `UserRequest` the right request? Sounds stupid but can happen.

Comment: @pmcpimentel Thanks you, I tried clearing all caches but it didn't help either, then I debugged, by removing rules one by one and looks like the problem was in nesting. I mean I had following rule: `'userDetails' => ['required', 'array']` and whatever was in `userDetails` array, was not being filtered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in nesting, I was accepting data with following structure:

```
$rules = [
   'userDetails' => ['required', 'array'],
   'userDetails.firstName' => ['required', 'string'],
   'userDetails.lastName' => ['required', 'string']
]
```

And whatever was passed in `userDetails` array was not being filtered, fixed by removing `'userDetails' => ['required', 'array']` from validation rules.

Looks like there's no need to use `array` validation